# Add a flight to ITA Matrix?

Tags: air-travel, connecting-flights, ita-matrix

The context for this question is google flights has Breeze Airways but ITA does not have Breeze Airways, and I really like the Time bars (and other features) on ITA.

For a clear concise example. Try booking on Google flights 04DEC2023 ORF to OAK. one way

And then change it to multi city with LAS
04DEC2023 ORF to LAS. 04DEC2023 LAS to OAK.

The same is available with 13MAR2024 and LAX instead of LAS

I understand Breeze (and Southwest) are not on ITA matrix, but as I book the flights directly with airlines and just use the software to find flights, this (and a few other flights) would be very useful for calculations, to the point, I would gladly manually add the one or two (dozen) flights I want included to like, a local ITA database addition. This is easiest with Breeze since they fly two flights a week between certain airports.

I understand this is likely a huge ask, so if the answer is "it's impossible". That's Okay with me. I figured the experts on ITA matrix were on the stack exchange as I've learned more here in a day of browsing than anywhere else, so if y'all say it's impossible, I'll give up immediately.

(Added confusion with Google flights, the default option is to show separate tickets, but it doesn't usually. I know this often adds baggage issues or flight delay issues, but this layovers for these flights are often hours above airport requirements)(and I don't check luggage or see why Google avoids them so heavily)

Comment: Oh if Google flights/ ITX Matrix are suboptimal for this kind of. A-C with any B flights. I'm willing to look into other options too? These just seem to be the most effective between multiple continental U.S. flights.

Answer (score 5):

"Matrix" has always been a bit of a playground for ITA Software.  They provided it as a free service, and used it to test their backend software which they then sold to companies such as travel agencies.

Then back in 2010 ITA Software was acquired by Google.  Whilst Matrix was maintained for a few years after that, it has now largely been deprecated. Parts of it are no longer available (eg, their mobile app), and whilst the website does continue to operate, it has not been upgraded in years and is lacking many modern features that mean it offer gives incorrect results - at least for some airlines.  (eg, those that use "Dynamic" fares, such many US airlines, plus even the ability to display/easily exclude exclude "Basic Economy" style fares).

From Google's perspective, Google Flights is the replacement for Matrix - and it does support most of those new features. However it is a slightly "dumbed down" version of Matrix and some of the more advanced functionality has been removed.

All of that is just a long way of saying that the odds of them *explicitly* adding anything to Matrix at this point is basically zero.  That's not to say that things like a new airline may not suddenly start showing, but such a change would come from a change on the backend GDS (global distribution system) they use, rather than a Matrix/ITA Software/Google change.